# Vue2 <script setup>: Why does simple example throw error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I used to define Vue2 components using classed based style and would like to migrate my codebase to the composition API. As I understand from the docs the composition API and the `script setup` method of writing single file components are supported in Vue 2.7. But even simple examples cause an error.

`package.json`

```
"vue": "2.7.14",
```

`test.vue`

```
<script setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'

  const count = ref(0);
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>
</template>
```

It compiles fine, but throws an error in the browser console:

```
App.js:144 Property or method "count" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties. 

found in

---> <Test> at test.vue
```

Any ideas why this fails?

Comment: This is specific to your setup which is responsible for compiling script setup syntax correctly. This doesn't happen for now

Comment: Is there any configuration to do to enable compiling script setup components?

Comment: This totally depends on your current setup, which is unknown

Comment: @EstusFlask do you know what does this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-v2-script-setup-d2vhr2?file=/src/App.vue) missing to make `<script setup>` work?

Comment: @Tolbxela Thanks, yummy. Checked it but no idea. Probably something related to vue cli and has something in common to the OP, or probably something related to codesandbox  itself. `setup` attr is clearly not recognized and treated as regular script block. vue loader and compiler versions are the first to blame but codesandbox doesn't show lock file to investigate this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround, you can use the [`setup()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#composition-api-setup) function to replace the `<script setup>` and still migrate to the Composition API

```
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
   setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    return { count }
   }
};
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="count++">Counter: {{ count }}</button>
</template>
```

I've got this working int this [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-v2-setup-70ch60?file=/src/App.vue)

---

According to the Vue Docs [Migration to Vue 2.7](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-2-7.html) the `<script setup>` should work with Vue 2.7.

But I'm also struggling to make it work with this [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-v2-script-setup-d2vhr2?file=/src/App.vue)

The `Composition API` does work. You can see it in the console output `{value: 0}`

But something is wrong with the template compiling.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a version issue, you will need to upgrade vue, if you don't want to upgrade to the latest version of vue then keep the normal options api way of doing things, there's nothing wrong with that. If you want to migrate to the composition api, then upgrade vue. The official state management library, pinia, requires vue3 anyways so if you later decide to add state management you will continue to run into problems.

Comment: Upgrade Vue to which version? 2.7.14 ist the latest Vue2. My codebase is not ready for Vue3 yet.

Comment: Pinia works also with Vue v2 https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/migration-v1-v2.html

Comment: That was my point, composition api was meant to use vue 3 and pinia is also something you may need and that was meant to run on vue 3 as well. Unless you want to migrate to vue 3 keep using the options api in vue 2, that's fine. I wouldn't start trying to use vue3 features in vue2

Comment: Right, I know it works but it requires one to install the vue composition library.

Comment: @dbzx10299 Vue 2.7 doesn't require `@vue/composition-api`, composition api is available from `vue` package

Answer (score 0):

My project with `vue cli 4` used `vue-template-babel-compiler` before, so I just rm it in `vue.config.js` and make sure the version of `vue-loader` in `package.json` is `15.10.0+`, see feat of `vue-loader` [release](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v15.10.0): compat for vue 2.7, support script setup

```js
// vue.config.js
chainWebpack(config) {
   // ...

   // rm follows:

    // config.module
    //   .rule('vue')
    //   .use('vue-loader')
    //   .tap((options) => {
    //     options.compiler = require('vue-template-babel-compiler')
    //     return options
    //   })

    // ...
}
```

work for me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same issue with Vite, to make the composition API work with Vue 2.7, you need to install the "@vitejs/plugin-vue2" package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-vue2

Once installed, import it in your vite.config.js file:

```
// vite.config.js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2'

export default {
   plugins: [vue()]
}
```

Best regards!